# Including a list of recent records in show method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to include a few other recent articles when someone views a particular article in my Rails app.

I have the following method in my controller:

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @recents = Article.where(!@article).order("created_at DESC").limit(4).offset(1)
end
```

As the expert eye might see, @recents isn't correct. It's my best guess. :)

How do I show some recent articles but not repeat the one they are currently viewing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a scope in the model, for it has a lot of advanteges. Learn about scopes [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes). Your case should be something like this:

In the model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :recent, ->(article_id) { where.not(id: article_id).order(created_at: :desc).limit(4) }
end
```

and in the controller:

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @recent = Article.recent(@article.id)
end
```

This way the recent scope will always get the four last articles leaving out the article you pass in as an argument. And scopes are chainable so you could do something like this as well:

```
def some_action
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])    
  @user_recent_articles = @user.articles.recent(0)
end
```

You are getting the user recent articles. I pass a zero because the scope asks for an argument. You could create a different scope if you want to do it the cleanest way. 
This, assuming a user has_many articles.

Well, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

try with `@recents = Article.where.not(id: @article.id).order("created_at DESC").limit(4)`

Answer (score 0):

[click here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) - section 2.4 :).
I think there is a way of only making one call instead of 2 the way you have it now.